# Drools Fusion and Java EE

Tags: jakarta-ee, drools, drools-fusion

What are the best practices for using Drools Fusion on a Web/Enterprise Application? Do you know of any useful document?

I've looked through the examples on JBoss (http://download.jboss.org/drools/release/5.1.1.34858.FINAL/drools-5.1.1-examples.zip), but they are Desktop Applications. I don't understand how to keep a Drools session "running" like that on a server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you can't find an example on the internet, it may be because it is not a good idea to do so. ;)

Please have a look at e.g. http://www.jboss.org/jbossesb. There you will see an example of a modern architecture. You may have several events, that are gathered and maybe correlated or filtered in a CEP engine like Drools Fusion. If the results need to be processed further, you send them via a service bus to the business services (your  web/enterprise application).

A web/enterprise application itself is not very strong in event processing. In the Java EE world you can trigger message driven beans via a Java message service. But this is far below the possibilities of a full blown CEP.

But: If you find a good approach to integrate the CEP engine in an AppServer, please let me know. :)